# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I would like to validate attributes in a function like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :check_name( :name )

  def check_name( name )
    ... if name is invalid ...
       self.errors.add( :name, 'Name is invalid')
  end

end
```

Can you please write the right code?
Please explain the functionality why...
THX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :check_name

  def check_name
    if name # is invalid ...
      self.errors.add(:name, 'Name is invalid')
    end
  end

end
```

You can use the `validate` macro but the method can't accept parameters.
You need to fetch the attribute value from inside the method, then validate it.

Replace

```
if name # is invalid ...
```

with your own validation logic.